# Sharepoint Designer 2010 Pause until date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, pause

I have created a workflow that checks for item status "Submitted", and should automatically change item status to "Pending" after 21 days (from "Date Out").

However it only seems to work when running the workflow manually and not automatically.

Can you help me what is wrong with this workflow and guide me on what to change so the workflow will work automatically?

[image]

By the way, workflow start options are manually, on item created and on item changed.

- Site: SharePoint 2010
- Workflow: SharePoint Designer 2010

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using **System Account** to trigger the workflow. **System Account** cannot trigger workflows automatically, it is by default.

Try test using different users which have Full control on the site, compare the result.